# Flight booked using my brother's credit card

Tags: airlines, sri-lankan-citizens

My brother has booked flights for my family using his credit card, and he is supposed to fly from another country. It is on Malindo Air and they asked for a copy of the passport of the person who purchased the tickets and an image of the front of his credit card.

Should we have also a letter from him, certifying that he purchased the tickets on our behalf?

Answer (score 2):

Supply what the company has requested, because that's what they want.

A letter "certifying" the purchase is worthless, as anyone could write it - it wouldn't have any weight.

A passport is an official document, and the card photocopy is to ensure that the purchaser does have physical access to the card itself

Comment: This.  It's an anti-fraud measure and can be a headache when the ticket was bought by someone else.  If he can't accompany you to the airport it might be possible for him to go in earlier and sign something to allow you to fly.